# How do I force delete kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following pods:

```
NAME                                                 READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
xxx-myactivities-79f49cdfb4-nwg22                      1/1       Terminating   0          10h
xxx-mysearch-55864b5c59-6bnwl                          1/1       Terminating   0          1d
xxx-mysearch-55864b5c59-rpn48                          1/1       Terminating   0          13h
xxx-mysearch-6ff9bbb7cb-9qgbb                          1/1       Terminating   0          3d
```

I am running the following code to forcefully delete those pods:

```
#
# Clean up dying pods
#
pods=$( kubectl get pods | grep -v Running | tail -n +2 | awk -F " " '{print $1}' )
for pod in $pods;
do
    kubectl delete pod $pod --force
done
```

Here is the output:

```
pod "xxx-myactivities-79f49cdfb4-nwg22" deleted
pod "xxx-mysearch-55864b5c59-6bnwl" deleted
pod "xxx-mysearch-55864b5c59-rpn48" deleted
pod "xxx-mysearch-6ff9bbb7cb-9qgbb" deleted
```

After cleaning up, those pods still hang around.

```
NAME                                                 READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
xxx-myactivities-79f49cdfb4-nwg22                      1/1       Terminating   0          10h
xxx-mysearch-55864b5c59-6bnwl                          1/1       Terminating   0          1d
xxx-mysearch-55864b5c59-rpn48                          1/1       Terminating   0          13h
xxx-mysearch-6ff9bbb7cb-9qgbb                          1/1       Terminating   0          3d
```

How do I clean up those pods?

Answer (score 96):

> To clean the pods you need to delete their **deployments namespace**.

First discover that deployments existed:

```
$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAME                               READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
chetabahana-web-584b95d576-62ccj   1/1       Running       0          20m
tutorial-web-56fbccc56b-wbwjq      1/1       Running       0          1m
```

Delete the deployment `<NAME>-xxxx` like this:

```
$ kubectl delete deployment <NAME>
```

For example to delete `tutorial-web-56fbccc56b-wbwjq` run:

```
$ kubectl delete deployment tutorial
```

Then all corresponded pods of `tutorial-xxxx` will terminate by itself.

```
NAME                               READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
chetabahana-web-584b95d576-62ccj   1/1       Running       0          20m
tutorial-web-56fbccc56b-wbwjq      0/1       Terminating   0          1m
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, delete the deployment not the pod or service, otherwise they will come back to life like zombies but with a different suffix.

Comment: All my deployments and replicasets were already deleted, yet there still were pods stuck in Terminating state. Only James Knott's answer helped me.

Comment: The terminology is not quite right in first line - the command actually deletes a deployment object, not a namespace.

Comment: This is answering a different question, which is "why do my pods keep restarting after I delete them". Surely useful for some people landing on this page from a web search, but not the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 92):

You have these alternatives:

```
kubectl delete pod xxx --now
```

Or

SSH into the node the stuck pod was scheduled on
Running `docker ps | grep {pod name}` to get the Docker Container ID
Running `docker rm -f {container id}`

Or

```
kubectl delete pod NAME --grace-period=0 --force
```

Comment: I think `--grace-period=0` sufficed, without `--force`.

Comment: This `--grace-period=0` without `--force` just hangs indefinitely, but the combination of both worked 

Comment: it just deletes pods, but if they have were deployed as 'deploymens' kubernetes will restore them. answer below (from @Chetabahana) solves the problem

Comment: The question is about deleting pods, not about deleting deployments. Note that the question clearly shows *the same pods* still existing after a deletion attempt, not new pods from the same deployment.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes...
Thanks! This should be the actual answer to this question

Answer (score 23):

For deleting pod forcefully use this.

`kubectl delete pod <Pod_Name> -n <namespace_name>  --grace-period=0  --force`

OR

`kubectl delete pod <Pod_Name> -n <namespace_name>  --wait=false`

For reference please follow below link.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/

Answer (score 9):

To delete all pods in terminating state with one command do:

```
for p in $(kubectl get pods | grep Terminating | awk '{print $1}'); do kubectl delete pod $p --grace-period=0 --force;done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces | awk '{if ($4 != "Running") system ("kubectl -n " $1 " delete pods " $2  " --grace-period=0 " " --force ")}'
```

you can use this command

Answer (score 2):

In case you used Helm to install the pod just run

```
helm delete Your_Deployment_Name -n The_Namespace
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is valuable to the question as the OP didn't mention Helm, and this solution does not force delete anything.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one to forcefully delete all pods that are not in a Running state:

```
kubectl get po | grep -v Running | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete po --force --grace-period=0
```

Make sure you are in the namespace you want to work with.

If you want to delete all pods in Running state, remove the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
kubectl get pods | grep part-of-the-pods-name|awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[1]}'|xargs -I {} kubectl delete pods {} --grace-period=0
```

additional grep can be added if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please wait and reconsider the approach. The force-killed pod in most situations will continue running, so its probably better idea to get inside the pod (using `kubectl exec` or `oc rsh`) and kill any offending processes first (e.g. those that exhaust resources). Once force-killed, the pod will no longer be accessible through the k8s API (its zombie processes that continue running despite pod being no longer there will then have to be killed by someone with the root on the host).