# Can't Scale Down Kubernetes Deployment (Overscaled)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I've got kubernetes running via docker (Running linux containers on a windows host).
I created a deployment (1 pod with 1 container, simple hello world node app) scaled to 3 replicas.

Scaled to 3 just fine, cool, lets scale to 20, nice, still fine.
So I decided to take it to the extreme to see what happens with 200 replicas (Now I know).

CPU is now 80%, the dashboard wont run, and I can't even issue a powershell command to scale the deployment back down.

I've tried restarting docker and seeing if I can sneak in a powershell command as soon as docker and kubernetes are available, and it doesn't seem to be taking.

Are the kubernetes deployment configurations on disk somewhere so I can modify them when kubernetes is down so it definitely picks up the new settings?

If not, is there any other way I can scale down the deployment?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you mean the Kubernetes that comes with docker. There is the reset option in docker under preferences (the bomb icon).  I guess you've already tried to force delete (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336665/how-do-i-force-delete-kubernetes-pods )?

Comment: @RyanDawson Yes I mean the kubernetes that comes with docker.  Thanks for pointing me to that SO question, I'm sure it will come in handy in the future, however I don't think it will help with my current problem, because (I assume) a deleted pod will just be re-created by the deployment when it noticed they're gone.  Ideally I need to reduce the number of replicas in a deployment outside of kubernetes if possible

Comment: Sorry I meant to suggest to delete the deployment. Does force help with that or you can't run that command either?

Comment: @RyanDawson oh right, I see what you mean.  Just tried it and unfortunately that's still not doing the job.

Comment: And docker preferences/factory reset also no good? You might be able to get some logs like https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2536#issuecomment-361861211 That thread gives rest instructions and also mentions increasing resource to docker but I'd suggest trying factory reset based on what you describe

Comment: @RyanDawson ahha! got it.  I had a look at the settings (As someone suggested in the link you provided) and increased the cpus and memory available to docker.
Glad I didn't need to resort to a factory reset, which I guess I'd have to do if I didn't have extra resources to supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2536 is a useful thread on this as it gives tips for getting logs, increasing resources or if necessary doing a factory reset (as discussed in the comments)